# Parse json from mysql in flask to get a field from record

Tags: python, mysql, json

Mind that I am new to flask and python for that matter, I appreciate any help that anyone gives. I'm looking to access one of the fields of my JSON response(just the field not the entire response), how should I go about parsing the response. Image of the response attached below,thanks.

## This is my main thread

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from Qhandler import Qhandler
from MakePlayer import MakePlayer
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/createplayer',methods=['GET','POST'] )
def showCreatePlayer():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        MakePlayer(request.form['playername'],request.form['playerteam'],request.form['playerrole'], request.form['playerpos'])
        return "created player: <br>"+request.form['playername']+" "+request.form['playerteam']+" "+request.form['playerrole']+" "+request.form['playerpos']

    return render_template("createPlayer.html")

@app.route('/sucess')
def success():
    return "success"

@app.route('/showplayers')
def showPlayers():
    Q = Qhandler()
    return Q.displayQuery(""" select * from Player""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### This is my query handler

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

class Qhandler(object):
    #global mysql
    global cursor
    global connection
    global mysql
    # database connection
    app = Flask(__name__)

    mysql = MySQL()
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'Optimizer'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    mysql.init_app(app)



    def ins(self,query):
        try:
            connection=mysql.connect()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            connection.commit()

        except:
            print "error running query"

        finally:
            #cursor.close()
            connection.close()

    def displayQuery(self,query):
        try:
            connection = mysql.connect()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            fetchedData = cursor.fetchall()
            fetchedData = jsonify(fetchedData)
            #fetchedData = json.dumps(fetchedData)
            #record = json.loads(fetchedData)
            #print "the resonse is here:"
            return fetchedData

        except:
            print "error running query"

        finally:
            #cursor.close()
            connection.close()
```

#### current response is

[screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYAJz.png)

Comment: Learn about JSON arrays and how to parse them with python.. google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "fetchedData = json.dumps(fetchedData)"  instead of  "fetchedData = jsonify(fetchedData)" then create a json decoder and parse the response, refer to below :

```
def displayQuery(self,query):
        try:
            connection = mysql.connect()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            fetchedData = cursor.fetchall()
            fetchedData = json.dumps(fetchedData)
            #create a json decoder
            d = json.JSONDecoder()
            fieldPlayerName = d.decode(fetchedData)
            #parse the json that is returned ( fieldPlayerName[0][1])
            print "should print the field with the player name",fieldPlayerName[0][1]
            return fieldPlayerName[0][1]
```